# Classify pdf files upon their name

Tags: weka, text-classification

I have list of pdf files (their names) like

1. Financial_Statement_Q1_2015_En **belongs to** Quarterly Report.
2. Financial_Statement_Yealy_2015 **belongs to** Not Quarterly Report.

I need to classify names of pdf's upon **Quarterly and Not Quarterly Reports**.
Kindly tell me the approach, how can I achieve this task using appropriate tool.

Comment: What languages do you know, you can do this is in pretty much every language by parsing the file name if you used a convention

Comment: I know c++,java,php.

Comment: @johnny , do I need to train dataset ??

Comment: Java is probably better  for this. You just going to want to Pull out all the pdf files name in the directory and iterate over them, create two list quaterly and not quaterly if the name contains Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 its quaterly else put it in the non quaterly

Comment: Are all the filenames structured like the examples you gave?

Answer (score 0):

When your files are named as openly as in your example, a simple pattern matching will work just fine.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
if "_Q\d_" in filename:
  print filename " belongs to quarterly reports"
else:
  print filename " does not belong to quarterly reports"
```